# onDestroy is not called for api 22

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, amazon-fire-os

I am using the androidx.navigation to navigate around the fragments.
I am seeing different behavior across different versions of FOS.
When i switch between the fragments  **onDestroy**

```
public void onDestroy() {}
```

is not called for api 21 and 22 right away. It gets called only when i try to create the same fragment again.

For api > 24, same method is called right away.

Whats the different? why this behavior, I have to do some cleanup which i am doing in onDestroy.
Should i use the onDestroyView instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `onDestroyView` is recommended for that purpose:

> onDestroyView() allows the fragment to clean up resources associated
> with its View.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks, however my question was, why its not being called on API 22